# iReport 5.6 SQL Server connect - using JTDS

Tags: sql-server, jasper-reports, ireport, jtds

Requirements are iReport 5.6, Java 6, and MS SQL Server 2012 using [`jtds-1.3.1.jar`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/files/jtds/1.3.1/jtds-1.3.1-dist.zip/download).

I cannot make **"MS SQLServer (net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver)" JDBC Driver** to *not* be red. I had that file *everywhere* trying to find the right place for it (because I've read many opinions on where it should be). I've also read that I need to add an entry to the */Tools/Options/Classpath/* area to point to the file. This didn't help either.

Where must I place the file and how must the CLASSPATH be set so that iReport can find the `.jar` file for SQL Server?

The real issue - I cannot use MS SQL Server (it's red here - needs to be black like the MySQL entry below it):

[image: Error Entry]

Where the jar file is located (I realize it shouldn't be in all of these places - I did test them one at a time):

[image: JAR File Location]

JAVA_HOME (cross reference with where the jar file is located):

[image: Java Home]

Added Classpath (also cross reference with where the jar file is located):

[image: Classpath]

It seems like it should be placed here, based on the other contents of the directory - `C:\Program Files (x86)\Jaspersoft\iReport-5.6.0\ide10\modules\ext`:

[image: EXT Directory]

Comment: SQL Server 2012. As mentioned - nobody else in the team (3 others) has any issues. Unfortunately the iReports expert left back in March - and I'm the replacement. I'm not bad with iReports itself, but setup is another animal.

Comment: Just tried the JDK ext directories as well. No dice. Something is deeply wrong here. It's driving me nuts.

Comment: I had tried that again this morning Dave (http://imgur.com/BXuauwo). I understand your frustration because it matches my own. Stupid (really dumb) question for you - is ODBC involved in this at all? I don't think it is - just want to be 100% positive.

Comment: It occurs to me that I'm the only one in our team using Windows 10 (new computer for new team member). I really wonder if that has anything to do with it. I've gotten permission to try and use the MS Driver at this point.

Answer (score 0):

After installing Jasper Reports 6.3, I was able to connect to the Server/DB immediately.

Seems iReport 5.6 and Windows 10 do not play well together.

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error, I had success on Mac OS using the following:

- iReports 5.6.0
- JDK 1.6 Official Mac version
- JTDS 1.2 (NOT 1.3.1 as it does not work due to requiring a later JDK)

I had issues getting iReports running on JDK 1.8 so had to downgrade to JDK 1.6.

I hope this helps some poor soul!

Comment: JTDS 1.2.8 with JDK 1.7 and iReports 5.6.0 is another working config on Mac OS 10.12.6.

Answer (score 0):

Please remember , iReport 5.6 is working with jre 7 and if you want to connect with MS SQL, you need driver sqljdbc41 (which is compatible with jre 7 in classpath)